# How to realize <Route children={({match})} => ... /> in a react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a modal which depended on a url.

[my modal in jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTf9o.png)

```
<Route
    path={`/preview/${params.id}`}
    children={({match}) => {
        return (
            <ModalWindow
                modalVisible={Boolean(match)}
                onCloseWindow={onCloseWindow}
                modalContent={modal}
            />
        )
    }}
/>
```

I am getting an error `A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>`.

But I already wrapped all my app in a  tag.

```
export default function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <Routes>
        <Route 
            path={"/home"}
            element={<HomeApp />}
        />
        <Route 
            path={"/preview/:id"}
            exact
            element={<HomeApp />}
        />
         <Route
            path={"/fullInfo/:id"}
            exact
            element={<HomeApp />}
         />
        <Route
            path={"*"}
            render={<Navigate to="/home"/>}
        />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

P.s I am new in `react-router-dom` of the new version.

Comment: Where are you trying to render the route for the modal? The `"/preview/:id"` path rendering `HomeApp` is masking it. Also, the redirect in your second snippet is incorrect, it should use the `element` prop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the rendered element in the `element` prop of your Route.So instead of :

```
 <Route
      path={"*"}
      render={<Navigate to="/home"/>}
  />
```

Do this:

```
 <Route
      path={"*"}
      element={<Navigate to="/home"/>}
  />
```

It is the same for the modal Route, you should wrap the component in the `element` prop of the Route